# reflect: How to get the name of a struct field?

Tags: reflection, go

```
type User struct { Name string }

func test(o interface{}) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(o)
    fmt.Println(t)
}

u := &User{"Bob"}
test(u.Name) // prints "string", but I need "Name"
```

Is this possible in Go? I want to have as few "magic strings" as possible, so instead of having

`UpdateFields("Name", "Password")`

I'd much rather use

`UpdateFields(user.Name, user.Password)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. The closest thing I can think of, but it's damn ugly so **do not take it as the answer** is something like this:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    Bar string
    Baz int
}

var Foo_Bar = reflect.TypeOf(Foo{}).Field(0).Name
var Foo_Baz = reflect.TypeOf(Foo{}).Field(1).Name

func main(){
    fmt.Println(Foo_Bar, Foo_Baz)
}
```

Comment: Too bad... Yeah that could actually work well with code generation.

Comment: But then it's easier to simply do `var Foo_Bar = "Bar"` :)

Comment: @Alex if you want code generation than you don't need reflect. Simply parse the struct definition and output a file that has consts for all fields. It will actually be cool, but again, just manually writing consts is also good.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work by defining a new type that is based off of string, and use that as the type inside of your struct:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type Name string
type User struct {
    Name Name
}

func test(o interface{}) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(o)
    fmt.Println(t.Name())
}

func main() {
    u := &User{"Bob"}
    test(u.Name) // Prints "Name"
    test("Tim") // Prints "string"
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Iit-4VzNDR).

Comment: Interesting, thanks! But I have about 50 SQL fields in my application, that would require creating 50 new types.